# Get percentage difference between two values (multiple instances)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the `result` function to run on each instance of `item`. The `result` is supposed to be the `percentage` of `value / max`. The function doesn't run when I use `value` and `max` as variables.

```js
$(".list").each(function() {
  var value = $(this)
    .closest(".item")
    .find(".value")
    .val();
  var max = $(this)
    .closest(".item")
    .find(".max")
    .val();
  var result = parseInt($(value) * 100) / parseInt($(max));

  if (!isFinite(result)) result = 0;

  $(".percent").val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Value
      <label>
    <input class="value" value="10" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
    <div>Max
      <label>
    <input class="max" value="50" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
    <div>% Complete
      <label>
    <input class="percent" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Value
      <label>
    <input class="value" value="40" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
    <div>Max
      <label>
    <input class="max" value="50" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
    <div>% Complete
      <label>
    <input class="percent" type="text">
  </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @mridula for an answer
Please, try to consider

```
$(".list .item").each(function() {
    const item = $(this);

    const value = item
        .find(".value")
        .val();

    const max = item
        .find(".max")
        .val();

    let result = parseInt(value * 100) / parseInt(max);

    if (!isFinite(result)) result = 0;

    item.find('.percent').val(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` and `max` are just variables holding the string values you are going to use to calculate.

Replace

```
 var result = parseInt($(value) * 100) / parseInt($(max));
```

By

```
var result = parseInt(value) * 100 / parseInt(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't Get percentage **difference** between two values From Above answer Because you are just getting percentage of first value compare to other value

Try this one

```
$(".item").each(function(element) {         

  var v1 = $(this).find("input.value").val(); 

  var v2 =  $(this).find("input.max").val();

  var maxV =Math.max(parseInt(v1),parseInt(v2));

  var minV =Math.min(parseInt(v1),parseInt(v2));

  var difV =maxV- minV;

    var result = (difV * 100) / maxV;   

    $(this).find("input.percent").val(result);
```

});